# Configurable product creates simple product as out of stock even if quantity given

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, out-of-stock

I have created a configurable product. Then I edited the "Configurations", so I have created simple products associated with the item. I set the quantity and saved.

But the simple products are saved as out of stock.
Is this a bug? Any fixes?

Magento ver. 2.1.3.

Comment: Add Quantity in your simple products as well , check it quantity field is empty for simple product ?

Comment: I did add quantity in the simple products. But not  in the "parent" configurable products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to give some quantity in the parent "configurable" product, save, then the simple product with the quantity was properly saved as "in stock".